# Python removing rows with time condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, spyder

I have 2 sets of Dataframe, both with an unique identifier and a datetime data in the format as such

"2020-01-01 00:00:01"-datetime and "12345" - unique identifier and Type

1st Question, DF1:

```
   DatetimeX            ID    Type
   2020-01-01 02:00:01 12345 C
   2020-01-01 02:00:03 12345 C
   2020-01-01 05:00:03 12345 C
   2020-01-01 05:03:05 12345 C
   2020-01-01 03:00:09 13333 D
   2020-01-01 02:00:09 12345 C
   2020-01-01 02:01:35 12345 C
   2020-01-01 02:10:35 12345 C
   2020-01-01 02:00:01 13333 D
   2020-01-01 02:05:35 13333 D
   2020-01-01 02:00:50 13333 E
   2020-01-01 02:00:01 12211 C
   2020-01-01 02:09:50 13333 E
   2020-01-01 02:11:50 13333 E
```

I would like to based on the ID's 1st time stamp with the same "Type", and remove the rows 10mins after as such:

```
   DatetimeX            ID    Type
   2020-01-01 02:00:01 12345 C
   2020-01-01 05:00:03 12345 C
   2020-01-01 02:10:35 12345 C
   2020-01-01 03:00:09 13333 D
   2020-01-01 02:00:01 13333 D
   2020-01-01 02:00:50 13333 E
   2020-01-01 02:00:01 12211 C
   2020-01-01 02:11:50 13333 E
```

I've tried to explore timerange/daterange but could not find any similar concept of coding. Would hope that if anyone can point out what kind of ways i can look into to explore and not trying to get a full solution. Have not touch python for a few years and not familiar with it previously. Thank you

**Updated with additional data row for more accurate example**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add sample input data and simplfied the process:

```
Timestamp = pd.to_datetime
data = [{'DatetimeX': Timestamp('2020-01-01 02:00:01'), 'ID': 12345, 'Type': 'C'},
 {'DatetimeX': Timestamp('2020-01-01 02:00:03'), 'ID': 12345, 'Type': 'C'},
 {'DatetimeX': Timestamp('2020-01-01 05:00:03'), 'ID': 12345, 'Type': 'C'},
 {'DatetimeX': Timestamp('2020-01-01 05:03:05'), 'ID': 12345, 'Type': 'C'},
 {'DatetimeX': Timestamp('2020-01-01 03:00:09'), 'ID': 13333, 'Type': 'D'},
 {'DatetimeX': Timestamp('2020-01-01 02:00:09'), 'ID': 12345, 'Type': 'C'},
 {'DatetimeX': Timestamp('2020-01-01 02:01:35'), 'ID': 12345, 'Type': 'C'},
 {'DatetimeX': Timestamp('2020-01-01 02:10:35'), 'ID': 12345, 'Type': 'C'},
 {'DatetimeX': Timestamp('2020-01-01 02:00:01'), 'ID': 13333, 'Type': 'D'},
 {'DatetimeX': Timestamp('2020-01-01 02:05:35'), 'ID': 13333, 'Type': 'D'},
 {'DatetimeX': Timestamp('2020-01-01 02:00:50'), 'ID': 13333, 'Type': 'E'},
 {'DatetimeX': Timestamp('2020-01-01 02:00:01'), 'ID': 12211, 'Type': 'C'},
 {'DatetimeX': Timestamp('2020-01-01 02:09:50'), 'ID': 13333, 'Type': 'E'},
 {'DatetimeX': Timestamp('2020-01-01 02:11:50'), 'ID': 13333, 'Type': 'E'}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)


col_raw = df1.columns
while True:
    df1.sort_values(['ID', 'Type', 'DatetimeX'], inplace=True)
    df1['diff1_lt10min'] = df1.groupby(['ID', 'Type'])['DatetimeX'].diff().dt.seconds < 10 * 60
    df1['tag_group'] = (~df1['diff1_lt10min']).cumsum()
    if df1.duplicated('tag_group').sum()==0:
        break
    df1 = df1.merge((df1.groupby('tag_group')['DatetimeX'].first()
               .reset_index()
               .rename(columns={'DatetimeX':'DatetimeX_1st'})),
              on='tag_group')
    df1['diff2_lt10min'] = (df1.DatetimeX - df1.DatetimeX_1st).dt.seconds < 10 * 60
    cond = df1['diff1_lt10min'] & df1['diff2_lt10min']
    df1 = df1.loc[~cond, col_raw]
df1 = df1[col_raw]
```

---

Detail...

```py
# repeat
col_raw = df1.columns
df4 = df1.copy()
n_round = 1
while True:
    print('#'*20, f'round {n_round}', '#'*20)
    # step 1 sort the values & group by ['Type', 'ID'] calculate the DatetimeX's time diff
    # notice: the time-diff is not the actual wanted
    df = df4[col_raw].copy()
    df.sort_values(['ID', 'Type', 'DatetimeX'], inplace=True)
    df['diff'] = df.groupby(['Type', 'ID'])['DatetimeX'].diff()
    print('#'*10, 'step1', '#'*10)
    print(df)

    # step 2, create a tag column to store the first 10min gap from 'diff' column
    cond = False 
    cond |= df['diff'].dt.seconds > 10 * 60
    cond |= df['diff'].isnull()
    df['tag'] = np.where(cond, 1, 0)
    df['tag'] = df['tag'].cumsum().fillna(method = 'ffill')
    print('#'*10, 'step2', '#'*10)
    print(df)

    # step 3, use 'tag' to judge to stop the while loop or not
    # tag should be unique
    break_sign = df.tag.duplicated().sum()
    if break_sign == 0:
        break
    print('#'*10, 'step3', '#'*10)
    print(break_sign)
    
    # step 4:
        # create a 'DatetimeX_1st' with the 'tag' group's first DatetimeX
        # create a 'diff2' = 'DatetimeX' - 'DatetimeX_1st'
    df2 = df.reset_index().set_index('tag')
    df2['DatetimeX_1st'] = df.groupby('tag').first()['DatetimeX']
    df2['diff2'] = df2['DatetimeX'] - df2['DatetimeX_1st']
    print('#'*10, 'step4', '#'*10)
    print(df2)
    
    # step 5:
        # drop the True < 10min gaps records
        # 'diff' and 'diff2' should all < 10min
    cond = (df2['diff2'].dt.seconds < 10 * 60) & (df2['diff'].dt.seconds < 10 * 60)
    df3 = df2[~cond].copy()
    print('#'*10, 'step5', '#'*10)
    print(df3)
    
    
    # step 6:
        # reset index
    cols = 'tag DatetimeX   ID  Type'.split()
    df4 = df3.reset_index().set_index('index').sort_index()[cols]
    print('#'*10, 'step6', '#'*10)
    print(df4)
    
    n_round += 1
    print()
    
# get result
result = df[['DatetimeX', 'ID', 'Type']].copy()
result.index.name = None
print()
print('#'*10, 'result', '#'*10)
print(result)
```

---

output:

```
#################### round 1 ####################
########## step1 ##########
             DatetimeX     ID Type            diff
11 2020-01-01 02:00:01  12211    C             NaT
0  2020-01-01 02:00:01  12345    C             NaT
1  2020-01-01 02:00:03  12345    C 0 days 00:00:02
5  2020-01-01 02:00:09  12345    C 0 days 00:00:06
6  2020-01-01 02:01:35  12345    C 0 days 00:01:26
7  2020-01-01 02:10:35  12345    C 0 days 00:09:00
2  2020-01-01 05:00:03  12345    C 0 days 02:49:28
3  2020-01-01 05:03:05  12345    C 0 days 00:03:02
8  2020-01-01 02:00:01  13333    D             NaT
9  2020-01-01 02:05:35  13333    D 0 days 00:05:34
4  2020-01-01 03:00:09  13333    D 0 days 00:54:34
10 2020-01-01 02:00:50  13333    E             NaT
12 2020-01-01 02:09:50  13333    E 0 days 00:09:00
13 2020-01-01 02:11:50  13333    E 0 days 00:02:00
########## step2 ##########
             DatetimeX     ID Type            diff  tag
11 2020-01-01 02:00:01  12211    C             NaT    1
0  2020-01-01 02:00:01  12345    C             NaT    2
1  2020-01-01 02:00:03  12345    C 0 days 00:00:02    2
5  2020-01-01 02:00:09  12345    C 0 days 00:00:06    2
6  2020-01-01 02:01:35  12345    C 0 days 00:01:26    2
7  2020-01-01 02:10:35  12345    C 0 days 00:09:00    2
2  2020-01-01 05:00:03  12345    C 0 days 02:49:28    3
3  2020-01-01 05:03:05  12345    C 0 days 00:03:02    3
8  2020-01-01 02:00:01  13333    D             NaT    4
9  2020-01-01 02:05:35  13333    D 0 days 00:05:34    4
4  2020-01-01 03:00:09  13333    D 0 days 00:54:34    5
10 2020-01-01 02:00:50  13333    E             NaT    6
12 2020-01-01 02:09:50  13333    E 0 days 00:09:00    6
13 2020-01-01 02:11:50  13333    E 0 days 00:02:00    6
########## step3 ##########
8
########## step4 ##########
     index           DatetimeX     ID Type            diff  \
tag                                                          
1       11 2020-01-01 02:00:01  12211    C             NaT   
2        0 2020-01-01 02:00:01  12345    C             NaT   
2        1 2020-01-01 02:00:03  12345    C 0 days 00:00:02   
2        5 2020-01-01 02:00:09  12345    C 0 days 00:00:06   
2        6 2020-01-01 02:01:35  12345    C 0 days 00:01:26   
2        7 2020-01-01 02:10:35  12345    C 0 days 00:09:00   
3        2 2020-01-01 05:00:03  12345    C 0 days 02:49:28   
3        3 2020-01-01 05:03:05  12345    C 0 days 00:03:02   
4        8 2020-01-01 02:00:01  13333    D             NaT   
4        9 2020-01-01 02:05:35  13333    D 0 days 00:05:34   
5        4 2020-01-01 03:00:09  13333    D 0 days 00:54:34   
6       10 2020-01-01 02:00:50  13333    E             NaT   
6       12 2020-01-01 02:09:50  13333    E 0 days 00:09:00   
6       13 2020-01-01 02:11:50  13333    E 0 days 00:02:00   

          DatetimeX_1st           diff2  
tag                                      
1   2020-01-01 02:00:01 0 days 00:00:00  
2   2020-01-01 02:00:01 0 days 00:00:00  
2   2020-01-01 02:00:01 0 days 00:00:02  
2   2020-01-01 02:00:01 0 days 00:00:08  
2   2020-01-01 02:00:01 0 days 00:01:34  
2   2020-01-01 02:00:01 0 days 00:10:34  
3   2020-01-01 05:00:03 0 days 00:00:00  
3   2020-01-01 05:00:03 0 days 00:03:02  
4   2020-01-01 02:00:01 0 days 00:00:00  
4   2020-01-01 02:00:01 0 days 00:05:34  
5   2020-01-01 03:00:09 0 days 00:00:00  
6   2020-01-01 02:00:50 0 days 00:00:00  
6   2020-01-01 02:00:50 0 days 00:09:00  
6   2020-01-01 02:00:50 0 days 00:11:00  
########## step5 ##########
     index           DatetimeX     ID Type            diff  \
tag                                                          
1       11 2020-01-01 02:00:01  12211    C             NaT   
2        0 2020-01-01 02:00:01  12345    C             NaT   
2        7 2020-01-01 02:10:35  12345    C 0 days 00:09:00   
3        2 2020-01-01 05:00:03  12345    C 0 days 02:49:28   
4        8 2020-01-01 02:00:01  13333    D             NaT   
5        4 2020-01-01 03:00:09  13333    D 0 days 00:54:34   
6       10 2020-01-01 02:00:50  13333    E             NaT   
6       13 2020-01-01 02:11:50  13333    E 0 days 00:02:00   

          DatetimeX_1st           diff2  
tag                                      
1   2020-01-01 02:00:01 0 days 00:00:00  
2   2020-01-01 02:00:01 0 days 00:00:00  
2   2020-01-01 02:00:01 0 days 00:10:34  
3   2020-01-01 05:00:03 0 days 00:00:00  
4   2020-01-01 02:00:01 0 days 00:00:00  
5   2020-01-01 03:00:09 0 days 00:00:00  
6   2020-01-01 02:00:50 0 days 00:00:00  
6   2020-01-01 02:00:50 0 days 00:11:00  
########## step6 ##########
       tag           DatetimeX     ID Type
index                                     
0        2 2020-01-01 02:00:01  12345    C
2        3 2020-01-01 05:00:03  12345    C
4        5 2020-01-01 03:00:09  13333    D
7        2 2020-01-01 02:10:35  12345    C
8        4 2020-01-01 02:00:01  13333    D
10       6 2020-01-01 02:00:50  13333    E
11       1 2020-01-01 02:00:01  12211    C
13       6 2020-01-01 02:11:50  13333    E

#################### round 2 ####################
########## step1 ##########
                DatetimeX     ID Type            diff
index                                                
11    2020-01-01 02:00:01  12211    C             NaT
0     2020-01-01 02:00:01  12345    C             NaT
7     2020-01-01 02:10:35  12345    C 0 days 00:10:34
2     2020-01-01 05:00:03  12345    C 0 days 02:49:28
8     2020-01-01 02:00:01  13333    D             NaT
4     2020-01-01 03:00:09  13333    D 0 days 01:00:08
10    2020-01-01 02:00:50  13333    E             NaT
13    2020-01-01 02:11:50  13333    E 0 days 00:11:00
########## step2 ##########
                DatetimeX     ID Type            diff  tag
index                                                     
11    2020-01-01 02:00:01  12211    C             NaT    1
0     2020-01-01 02:00:01  12345    C             NaT    2
7     2020-01-01 02:10:35  12345    C 0 days 00:10:34    3
2     2020-01-01 05:00:03  12345    C 0 days 02:49:28    4
8     2020-01-01 02:00:01  13333    D             NaT    5
4     2020-01-01 03:00:09  13333    D 0 days 01:00:08    6
10    2020-01-01 02:00:50  13333    E             NaT    7
13    2020-01-01 02:11:50  13333    E 0 days 00:11:00    8

########## result ##########
             DatetimeX     ID Type
11 2020-01-01 02:00:01  12211    C
0  2020-01-01 02:00:01  12345    C
7  2020-01-01 02:10:35  12345    C
2  2020-01-01 05:00:03  12345    C
8  2020-01-01 02:00:01  13333    D
4  2020-01-01 03:00:09  13333    D
10 2020-01-01 02:00:50  13333    E
13 2020-01-01 02:11:50  13333    E
```

Comment: Thank you for the step by step break down. Was trying the method and met some errors at Step 3. Error message "None of ['tag'] are in the columns" were shown. Any idea how I can tackle this? Tried" df6 = df.reset_index()
    df6.set_index('tag')" but met error of length mismatch

Comment: Sorry, step 4 @Ferris

Comment: Sorry, my bad, typo on my end in the code

Comment: Hi sorry, it was running fine but i accidentally unplug my power source and my codes are gone T^T. Couldnt verify

Comment: Hi, managed to retrieve my code and started trying. Realised that before step one, at df = df4[col_raw].copy(), it actually dropped some of the rows. e.g. i have data for ID 12345 for 5 different date, after running at the while loop, 2 of the dates were dropped. Trying to find out why it happened but cant seems to find it

Comment: you can split the code, and run it step by step in jupyter notebook or ipython, and find out what happened on every line execute.

Comment: Manage to identify the issue that causes missing of certain rows. I've converted the datetime.diff into seconds for comparison. The comparison from your solution were just done by comparison seconds which thus did not include the day. After changing to compare by total seconds, the result is successful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you should try `groupby`:

```
>>> df.groupby((df.Type != df.Type.shift()).cumsum(), as_index=False).first()
            DatetimeX     ID Type
0 2020-01-01 02:00:01  12345    C
1 2020-01-01 02:00:01  13333    D
2 2020-01-01 02:00:50  13333    E
3 2020-01-01 02:00:01  12211    C
>>>
```

It groups by consencutive same values.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the guidance provided. I tried the code and it work but it seems to remove the row of 3 hours difference from my own set of data. Will need to fix the time range of 10mins. Any data within 10mins of the 1st time stamp needs to be removed

Answer (score 0):

Based on your statement **I would like to based on the ID's 1st time stamp with the same "Type", and remove the rows 10mins**, I believe you can use `groupby().transform()` to identify the first timestamps, then use boolean masking:

```
# also transform('min')
first_timestamps = df.groupby(['ID','Type'])['DatetimeX'].transform('first')

mask = df['DatetimeX'] - first_timestamps < pd.Timedelta('10Min')

df[mask]
```

However, since your sample data all have time within 10 mins from each other, this wouldn't cut anything from it.

Instead, if we change `10Min` to `1S` in the second line above, we have the expected output:

```
            DatetimeX     ID Type
0 2020-01-01 02:00:01  12345    C
4 2020-01-01 02:00:01  13333    D
6 2020-01-01 02:00:50  13333    E
7 2020-01-01 02:00:01  12211    C
```

Comment: Thank you for the help provided. I've tried the codes as shown above but met with some issues. As i have a set of data of up to 3000 rows, when I use the codes for testing, there were 2 scenario faced. e.g1. if i have 2 data within a day, both were removed. e.g2. I still have data there are within 10mins