# Merging of 2 separate excel file based 3 condition using python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spyder

1st Step of my question which is currently not solved is in [Python removing rows with time condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65821366/python-removing-rows-with-time-condition)

2nd Step of the Question: After having the filter data from step 1, would like to do a join from DF1 to DF2 based on the condition of same ID and Type and join the nearest Datetime from DF 2 to DF 1 (Date time of DF1 must be after DF2)

E.g. DF1 -  EXIT data

```
   DatetimeX            ID    Type
   2020-01-01 02:00:01 12345 C
   2020-01-01 02:00:01 13333 D
   2020-01-01 02:00:50 13333 E
   2020-01-01 16:00:01 12211 C
   2020-01-02 21:00:01 12211 C
   2020-01-03 17:00:01 12211 C
   2020-01-04 17:00:01 12211 C
   2020-01-05 21:00:01 12211 C
```

E.g. DF2 - ENTRY data

```
   DatetimeE            ID    Type
   2020-01-01 01:00:00 12345 C
   2020-01-01 00:00:01 77777 C
   2020-01-01 00:00:05 12345 C
   2020-01-01 00:00:20 12345 C
   2020-01-01 02:00:05 13333 D
   2020-01-01 04:00:50 13333 E
   2020-01-01 07:00:01 12211 C
```

Endstate after join e.g. DF3

```
   DatetimeX            ID   Type DatetimeE
   2020-01-01 02:00:01 12345 C    2020-01-01 01:00:00 
   2020-01-01 02:00:01 13333 D
   2020-01-01 02:00:50 13333 E
   2020-01-01 02:00:01 12211 C    2020-01-01 01:00:30 
   2020-01-02 21:00:01 12211 C    2020-01-01 07:00:01
```

I've tried exploring merge and merge_asof but the combined data of DF3 does not match any of the data. Would like to just request for some guidance on how I can start comparing.

Thank you!

**Updated with more data sample**

Comment: how about `DF3 = DF1.merge(DF2, how='left', on=['ID', 'Type'])`

Comment: There are 3 conditions to fulfil for merging. 1. ID, 2 Type and 3. the nearest timing of df2 which is also not after the datetime of df1

Comment: okay check the solution

Answer (score 0):

```py
DF1['DatetimeX'] = pd.to_datetime(DF1['DatetimeX'])
DF2['DatetimeE'] = pd.to_datetime(DF2['DatetimeE'])

output = []

for index, row in DF1.iterrows():
    output.append(DF2[(DF2['ID'] == row['ID']) & (DF2['Type'] == row['Type']) & (DF2['DatetimeE'] < row['DatetimeX'])]['DatetimeE'].max())

DF1['DatetimeE'] = output
```

another way using `apply`

```py
DF1['DatetimeX'] = pd.to_datetime(DF1['DatetimeX'])
DF2['DatetimeE'] = pd.to_datetime(DF2['DatetimeE'])

DF1['DatetimeE']  = DF1.apply(lambda row: DF2[(DF2['ID'] == row[1]) & (DF2['Type'] == row[2]) & (DF2['DatetimeE'] < row[0])]['DatetimeE'].max(), axis=1)
```

output

```
DatetimeX   ID  Type    DatetimeE
0   2020-01-01 02:00:01 12345   C   2020-01-01 01:00:00
1   2020-01-01 02:00:01 13333   D   NaT
2   2020-01-01 02:00:50 13333   E   NaT
3   2020-01-01 02:00:01 12211   C   2020-01-01 01:00:30
```

Comment: Hi! I tried the above codes but my output returns "NaT" for all. Any idea why?

Comment: Hi! I noticed that your output is missing 1 row of data. The final row of my output example

Comment: Give me some time, I will check and correct

Comment: Thank you! Your help is deeply appreciated! As of now I manage to merge the data using your method but encounter duplicate DatetimeE. "2020-01-01 01:00:30 " will appear twice in both timing of DatetimeX